# Text running into footer area when using amsart and fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, amsart

I'm trying to include a logo in the footer area of an amsart document. I use fancyhdr to achieve that, but the problem I run into is that the body of the text runs into the footer area - as illustrated by the example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\lfoot{\rule{0.4cm}{0.4cm}} %The logo would go here
\cfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Doc}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Has anybody run into a similar problem or know of a quick fix? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `\setlength{\footskip}{4ex}` ?

Comment: And please update the title of your question, this has nothing to do with footnotes, but rather the footer area (footnotes are a part of the text area)

Comment: Many thanks to all those who answered. I have updated the question title in line with the suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `amsart` way to this is to increase `\footskip`, decrease the default `\textheight` correspondingly and then issue `\calclayout`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\lfoot{\rule{0.4cm}{0.4cm}} %The logo would go here
\cfoot{Page \thepage}

\advance\footskip0.4cm
\textheight=54pc    %a4paper
%\textheight=50.5pc %letterpaper
\advance\textheight-0.4cm
\calclayout

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Doc}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The command `\calclayout` is specific to the AMS classes.  One specifies an initial `\textheight` that includes headers, but not footers, and also one specifies `\textwidth`, `\headsep`, `\headheight`, `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`.  `\calclayout` then computes the correct value of page margins, ensuring some reasonable minimum values, and then `\textheight` is set to the height of the textblock.  Looking at the code, the calculations ignore the footers.  By default no adjustment is made to e.g. `\headheight` for the font size.  The class is really designed to work with the default `10pt` option.

The initial values given to `\textheight` in the above code, are those from `amsart.cls` for `a4paper` and `letterpaper` (the only paper options the class accepts).

Comment: Wow I've never heard of `\calclayout`. Can you give a bit more details on this, please? Is it AMS-specific?

Comment: @tohecz Explanation added, and coded updated according to what I found out in the process!

Answer (score 3):

You have to give proper `footskip`. This can be done easily with `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.4in,heightrounded]{geometry}
```

I have added some more useful options to `geometry`.

```
\documentclass[reqno,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.4in,heightrounded]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\lfoot{\rule{0.4cm}{0.4cm}} %The logo would go here
\cfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Doc}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the values suitably and beware of other quantities like `headheight`, `headsep` etc. For details refer to `geometry` documentation at [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net).