# Text running into footer area!

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to create a template for my short reports (3-5 pages). I would like to have a header and a footer on each page.

I have managed the most of it but I am running into an issue and would greatly appreciate a solution to this problem.

I reviewed the previous questions and there was answer to a question ( [Text running into footer area when using amsart and fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154393/text-running-into-footer-area-when-using-amsart-and-fancyhdr))
 but when I implement that suggestion, my header disappears.

Here is the code I am using and a screenshot to illustrate the issue.

Thank you,
Jay

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{datetime}

\lhead{ \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=1cm]{logo-img-3}}
\rhead{\begin{Large} faucibus maximus\end{Large}\\    \begin{small}LQuisque ex dui, tincidunt eu metus ut \end{small}}
\fancyfoot[L]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur }
\fancyfoot[R]{\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{33pt}

\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\vspace*{5ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{Huge} Aliquam malesuada ex libero \end{Huge}\\
\end{center}

\vspace{0.5in}
\begin{center}
\begin{Huge} consectetur adipiscing \end{Huge}\\
\end{center}


\clearpage
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | r |}
\hline
col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
\hline \hline
col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
\hline
col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
\hline
col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! If you use `geometry`, do not set page layout dimensions manually as it will throw off the calculations. In this case `geometry` doesn't know you've changed `\headheight` so it doesn't take any account of it.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't generate the image posted. It doesn't demonstrate the issue. At least, it doesn't when I substitute your image with `example-image-a`. Obviously, I don't have your image itself. What is the vertical space before `\begin{document}` supposed to do?

Comment: warning -- `amsart` isn't set up to coexist happily with either `fancyhdr` or `geometry`; the page layout is defined to produce the output required by the in-house platemaker in our printing department.  so using instructions meant for `amsart` isn't likely to produce the results you are looking for when you are using `article`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

[image: sample output]

If you use `geometry`, do not set page layout dimensions manually as it will throw off the calculations. In this case `geometry` doesn't know you've changed `\headheight` so it doesn't take any account of it. The problem can be corrected by changing the dimension using `geometry`'s facilities.

Code for above sample:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{datetime}
\lhead{ \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
\rhead{\Large faucibus maximus\\\small LQuisque ex dui, tincidunt eu metus ut}
\fancyfoot[L]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur }
\fancyfoot[R]{\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\geometry{headheight=33pt}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{5ex}
\begin{center}
  \Huge Aliquam malesuada ex libero
  \vspace{0.5in}

  \Huge consectetur adipiscing
\end{center}
\kant[1-10]
\clearpage
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | r |}
  \hline
  col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
  \hline \hline
  col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
  \hline
  col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
  \hline
  col1  & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 \\ [1ex]
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your quick response. your proposed code works nicely. I have another question: how do I remove the weekday from the day in the footer? I just need the day of the month and year (no week day). Many Thanks, Jay

Comment: Never mind! I replaced \usepackage{datetime} with \usepackage{advdate} and I now have the date format I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You could also do it with `datetime` but if `advdate` does what you need, you already have a solution ;).